# .NET client (Service Reference) does not work with ASP.NET OData Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, rest, odata

I have an ASP.NET Web API project exposing OData (note that I am not using Entity Framework rather I am returning data from a custom source). I want to be able to take advantage of .NET LINQ query support on client side but it seems that adding service reference on client requires the data to be returned as "application/atom+xml" format whereas be default ASP.NET web api Odata returns either application/json or application/xml.

Is there an easy way to be able to write linq style odata queries on client side with an asp.net web api odata service?
If not then is converting my service to WCF from asp.net is the only choice that I have?

Answer (score 0):

You could use OData client code generator to generate the Odata client code automatically by passing OData service metadata. Then you can use Linq to query from client side. The following blog can be refereed to.
[The ASP.NET Web API 2.2 for OData release and the OData Client Code Generator release](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/03/21/the-asp-net-web-api-2-2-for-odata-release-and-the-odata-client-code-generator-release.aspx)

The Linq code is like the following:
`var q1 = TestClientContext.CreateQuery<Type>("Accounts").Where(acct => acct.ID == 101);`

Comment: I get the following error:

"Running transformation: System.InvalidOperationException: The element 'edmx:Edmx' was unexpected for the root element. The root element should be Edmx."

Following is what I see in the metadata returned by my service:
<edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="3.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0" 
        xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">

I am not sure how to upgrade my server to use Odata version 4. My using ASP.NET Web API with Odata and Rest protocol.

Comment: Could you try add service reference, which is for V3:[Click Here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/calling-an-odata-service-from-a-net-client)

Comment: Maya is right. By default Scafolding in VS creats Web.API Odata service v3. You can find something like this "<edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="3.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0">" in your service metadata output (http://localhost:xxxxx/odata/$metadata). Client Code Generator will work for OData V4 services only.